# Why do I get a 'referenced before assignment' error, for a variable that has been assigned in the global scope?

Tags: python, python-3.x

This code:

```
my_num = 0

def my_func():
  my_num = my_num + 1
my_func()
```

causes the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "main.py", line 5, in
>   
>       my_func()   File "main.py", line 4, in my_func
>       my_num = my_num + 1 UnboundLocalError: local variable 'my_num' referenced before assignment

Why does the interpreter not read the expression as:

```
my_num = 0 + 1
```

Comment: Because you didn't say inside the function that you wanted to use the global one. Research the error message.

Comment: If I wrote:
`x = my_num + 1` it would work, however.

Comment: Yes, because then there's no ambiguity - x is only local, my_num is only global

Comment: Where does the ambiguity arise? I don't understand, I would think that the variable defaults to the parent if it is not assigned within the local scope.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+unboundlocalerror

Comment: *Why does the interpreter not read the expression* - that is because the variable is declared local by the **compiler**. So when the interpreter tries to evaluate it in the RHS, it is not yet initialized (in its local scope). Read more in the [official docs](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#why-am-i-getting-an-unboundlocalerror-when-the-variable-has-a-value)

Answer (score 0):

Because you can *read* the values of global variables without doing anything special, but not *write* them unless you use the `global` keyword.

In this line `my_num = my_num + 1` you are trying to *read* **and** *write* a global variable. Since you didn't specify that `my_num` is a global variable with `global my_num` in your function, the interpreter sees the left hand side of the assignment as a new local variable, and thus the right hand side variable doesn't make any sense.

Any value that is assigned to in a function is treated as a local variable unless there is an explicit `global` statement. [**From the docs**](https://docs.python.org/3.8/reference/simple_stmts.html):

> Assignment of an object to a single target is recursively defined as
>   follows.
>
> - If the target is an identifier (name):
>
>   - If the name does not occur in a [`global`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/reference/simple_stmts.html#global) or [`nonlocal`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/reference/simple_stmts.html#nonlocal) statement in the
>       current code block: the name is bound to the object in the current
>       local namespace.

Comment: Does the interpreter read the left hand side first? If it read the right hand side first then it would use the global variable and then recognise that a new variable is being declared.

Comment: @rcwhiteley It evaluates the right hand side first.

Comment: So surely the interpreter uses the global value of `my_num` on the right hand side and then creates a new local variable on the left hand side. I am trying to understand why this causes an error.
I know I could avoid this by using the keyword global, but trying to understand how the interpreter works.

Comment: @rcwhiteley Any value that is assigned to in a function is treated as a local variable unless there is an explicit `global` statement.

Comment: @rcwhiteley Evaluation order is different than the parsing order.

Comment: @rcwhiteley Evaluation order is RHS then LHS. The problem is that the **compiler** defines the variable as local. So by the time the interpreter tries to evaluate the variable, it is not yet defined in the **local scope** and hence the error

Comment: Thank you, @Tomerikoo. Your explanation is what makes sense to me, I did not know that Python is compiled and then interpreted! I thought it was just an 'interpreted' language. That makes sense that the variable has been defined as local, so it makes sense why the interpreter does not assign the global variable to it.

Comment: @rcwhiteley glad to help. I also commented on the question with a link from the docs that might help clear things up

Answer (score -1):

You need to declare my_num as global:

```
    def my_func():
      global my_num
      my_num = my_num + 1
```